# How was the robot controller prop made in The Runaway Bride?

Tags: doctor-who, props

In Doctor Who's 2006 Christmas special [The Runaway Bride](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Runaway_Bride), one prop used is a remote controller for the killer Santa bots. The prop is obviously a redressed console controller. It looks like it has two sets of buttons on top, like a PS2/3's L1, L2, R1, and R2 buttons. Yet it's not quite that.

What type of controller was used to make the prop?

Comment: Shouldn't this be on movies.SE?

Comment: @DVK Didn't know about that one. There's no "Off Topic -> Move to movies.SE", probably because it's still in beta, but if there was, I'd vote for the move myself.

Comment: I don't see any reason to migrate a question that's on topic for us, and has already been answered.

Answer (score 5):

[Found it](http://www.tv.com/shows/doctor-who-2005/the-runaway-bride-813283/):

> The controller, while it may have the shape of a Playstation 2 control pad, is in fact a heavily modified Nintendo 64 pad. You can tell this as the N64 pad has three handles and not two (you can even see the exposed port for the 'rumble pack'). The middle handle also protrudes out the longest (with a mini-joystick) too.

You can see a concept art photo from the BBC 'Doctor Who gallery';
[image]

and the finished product here; 
[image]

Comment: Ahhh N64... Good times... But yeah you could totally tell it was a modified N64 controller just from the 2nd pictures..